# Как реализовать прослушивание rtsp порта для воспроизведения ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

Всем привет!
Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь реализовать воспроизведение медиа потока средствами ffmpeg по rtsp под Linux. С самим воспроизведение проблем нет, а вот как реализовать чтобы программа слушала по rtsp определенный порт и только после получения данных на него начинала непосредственные действия, вот тут то и загвоздка....
Может есть примеры реализации таких алгоритмов или где посмотреть, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Читать: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp

```
rtsp_flags
  listen
```

Из секции [примеров](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#Examples):

```
Receive a stream in realtime:

  ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen -i rtsp://ownaddress/live.sdp output
```

Читайте доки - они рулез.

Comment: В консоли то понятно... там проблем нет... )))).... я имел в виду закодить на С++ прослушивание. Смотрел код ffplay, но как то не особо дошло как там это реализовано....

Comment: Даже взял вынес ffplay отдельным проектом в QT4. Скомпилировал. При запуске с параметрами например " -rtsp_flags listen rtsp://127.0.0.1:5010" следующий вывод:  
[tcp @ 0x8ccf20] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:5010?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0

Comment: Так эти же параметры и в коде используются. Вы когда формат открываете, ему словарь с параметрами передётся, вот и нужно добавить в словарь значение параметр `rtsp_flags` со значением `listen`. После чего открытие и `av_read_packet()` - вызов завершится, как только первый пакет на входе появится. Можно назначить interrupt callback, если есть потребность прервать ожидание.

Comment: Посмотрите https://github.com/h4tr3d/avcpp возьмите от туда любой семпл с чтением и вооружившись https://github.com/h4tr3d/avcpp/blob/master/example/api2-samples/api2-dict-basic.cpp дополните открытие формата заданием словаря.

Comment: Спасибо! буду разбираться....

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию

```
AVFormatContext * avfc;
avformat_open_input(&avfc,"rtsp://127.0.0.1:5010/h264_2",NULL,NULL);
```

При открытии rtsp потока нужно указать адрес:порт:файл_доступа